# Why is that slot called twice?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wrote a minimal PyQt5 app which just shows a button and connects it's `clicked` signal to a method printing some string:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class HelloWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('hello.ui', self)

    def on_hello_button_clicked(self):
        print("Hello")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HelloWindow()
    window.show()
    raise SystemExit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Strangely `on_hello_button_clicked` - which gets autoconnected is being called twice when I press the button..

What's happening here?

This is `hello.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>324</width>
    <height>87</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="hello_button">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I'm using PyQt5 5.14 installed using pip, on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [connecting slots by name](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name) mechanic of PyQt5. The problem is, that there are two `clicked` [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) in `QAbstractButton`. One is `clicked()` and the other is `clicked(bool)`. Since overloading methods in python is not possible, both signals trigger your `on_hello_button_clicked` method.

You can avoid this by explicitly defining the `on_hello_button_clicked` method to receive the signals from `clicked()`, by adding the `pyqtSlot` decorator from `PyQt5.QtCore`, e.g.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class HelloWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_hello_button_clicked(self):
        print("Hello")
```